# Plone 4: create a folder using one of personal information at first login

Tags: plone

We know that at first login Plone can create a folder for each user.
If username is "user" the folder's name will be "user". The folder name can be edited, but for a lot of users this operation is really crazy.
I've customized the register form and added new field.
Can I use one of this field to give that folder the name?
For example in the register form there is a field named "company name" and the user type "supercompany".
The goal is that at first login Plone must create the folder with the name "supercompany".
Is it possible with PLone 4?

Comment: No - unless you customize it. The problem is?

Comment: The problem is to do it automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is always a way because Plone is 100% open source software and there is no part you could not change in it.

The related code of the member folder creation is here:

https://github.com/plone/Products.PlonePAS/blob/master/Products/PlonePAS/tools/membership.py#L271

In your case I suggest a simple customization add-on with a monkey-patch should do it for you.

http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/misc/monkeypatch.html